# R: Barplots & Separating them by variables

Tags: r

I've been given a data set & I've converted it into a matrix. I've been wondering how to create a barplot based on the values from the matrix from the columns. I basically have to compare 2 variables which are the year they were operated on & their Survival Status. Their survival status is based on 2 values, 1 is they live beyond 5 years and 2 is they died within 5 years. and I want to compare both to the other variable depending whether or not they were operated on before 1965 & after 1965. So in total I'm looking for 4 bars in total, 1 being they were operated before 1965 and survived, another being they were operated before 1965 and died, another being they were being operated on after 1965 and survived and another being they were operated on after 1965 and died. It would really be appreciated if some-one could help me! My code follows below:

```
data<-data.matrix(readingfile)
Survival<-c(data[,4])
Year<-c(data[,2])
Comparison<-matrix(c(Year,Survival),ncol=2)
barplot(Comparison) # I know it's this line of code I will have to add arguments in, in order to make it work.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your problem. So I offer you a solution that is very basic and I separate all the stages, so that there must be something useful somewhere for you ;-)

Let me know how it goes !

```
# Let's first create some fake data
survival <- sample(1:2, 100, replace=T)
year <- sample(1940:1990, 100, replace=T)
comparison <- data.frame(year, survival)

# We sum each category for each year
sum.per.year <- rbind(tapply(comparison$survival, comparison$year, function(x) sum(x==1)),
    tapply(comparison$survival, comparison$year, function(x) sum(x==2)))
# We create a logical vector to check what years are in the period we target
year.before.1965 <- sapply(colnames(sum.per.year), function(c) as.numeric(c)<1965)
# Now we aggregate (sum) the results for before and after 1965
sum.per.year <- t(data.matrix(sum.per.year))
res <- sapply(1:2,function(c) tapply(sum.per.year[,c],year.before.1965,sum))
colnames(res) <- c("Lived.over.5","Died.in.5")
rownames(res) <- c("Before.1965","After.1965")

# And finally we output
barplot(res, beside=T, col=c("blue","red"))
legend("topleft", rownames(res), pch=15, col=c("blue","red"), bty="o")

# OR, depending on what how you want to present the results
barplot(t(res), beside=T, col=c("blue","red"))
legend("topleft", colnames(res), pch=15, col=c("blue","red"), bty="o")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you so much! Not quite what I expected with the results but nevertheless this has helped me greatly! Once again thank you! :)